# iPhone simulator black screen in xcode 4.1 on Lion (iAtkos L1)

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator, xcode4.1

i am new to mac and i started working on iOS programming. Recently i get problem when i run or click on Build & Go button (in Xcode 4.1), my project does building but Xcode isn't able to run my application in iPhone simulator. I just see blacnk black screen.

i have tried different project templates but it doesn't work and by the wary i m working in view based application template.

But when i start iPhone simulator outside of Xcode, it does run in good condition. i don't get the black screen.

Please! help me solve this problem. Because i want to work on iPhone applications.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Base SDK is as high or higher than the version of iOS on your iPhone. Also make sure that your compiler is set to the newest as well.  If you are building with iOS 5 you need to switch to LLVM Compiler (under project and target settings) and LLDB debugger (under edit scheme).

Answer (score 0):

When I get a black screen in the simulator the first thing I check is that I have checked the "Is Initial View Controller" for one of my views.  I'll attach a photo.[image]